# Change text if user is logged in

Tags: php, html, variables, session

Once someone logs in, I want to be able to show their username instead of a text that's already there.
I want `<li><a href="profile.html"><?php $_SESSION['username'] ?></a>` in the texterMember.php to show the username of the person that logged in

Here is part of my login.php

```
(Other Stuff)

if(password_verify($password1, $result))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("texter.php","_self");</script>';
}else{
    echo json_encode("0");  
}

(Other Stuff)
```

This is my texter.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
?>
<!-- Start Members-->
<?php include('texterMember.php'); ?>
<!-- End Members -->
<?php

} else {
?>
<!-- Start Guest -->
<?php include('texterGuest.html'); ?>
<!-- End Guest -->
<?php
}
```

Here is part of my texterMember.php

```
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="profile.html"><?php $_SESSION['username'] ?></a>
            </li>
            <li class="current"><a href="texter.php">Text Bomber</a>
            </li>
            <!--<li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
            </li>
            <li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to print the session's `username` variable like this:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>
```

Instead of existing

```
<?php $_SESSION['username'] ?>
```

[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: That will but, in cases where short_open_tags are not enabled, it will return code as plain HTML instead of executing.

Comment: In newer PHP versions `<?=` isn't considered short tag.

Comment: @Forien, yes,  I agree.  But,  I took care of backwards compability.